# hdfs test result only displayed after typing $?

Tags: bash, sh

How come when I run the command:

`hdfs dfs -test -d /user/me/dirs`

I have to type in `$?` to get the result:

`sh: 0: command not found`

Is there a way I could just get the result (0 or 1)itself and none of the other text?

Pretty terrible at bash so I might be missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, `$?` gives you the exit code of the previous command. Simply typing `$?` will cause your shell to attempt to execute that return code as a command (which is not usually what you want). You could instead print the value using `echo $?`, or save it in a variable using `retcode=$?`.

Exit codes are not normally printed to your shell. The reason you may not be seeing any other output is because the `hdfs` command is likely not printing any text to your screen (either through `stdout` or `stderr`).

I suspect your best option might be `hdfs dfs -test -d /user/me/dirs; echo $?`, or some variant using a variable.

- [Exit codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)
- [Understanding exit codes and how to use them in bash scripts](http://bencane.com/2014/09/02/understanding-exit-codes-and-how-to-use-them-in-bash-scripts/)